# Create stripe token cURL with angular and reactive forms

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe for the paymanet in my app, but I get stoke in the moment that I send my card form I'm using reactive forms to get the value of the inputs and send it to the service. but the service return me the values like this.

```
{"card[number]":"424242424242","card[exp_month]":"02","card[exp_year]":"22","card[cvc]":"123"}
```

I'm using the cURL to send the data. in the docs the example is like this

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens \
  -u sk_test_{KEY}: \
  -d "card[number]"=4242424242424242 \
  -d "card[exp_month]"=11 \
  -d "card[exp_year]"=2021 \
  -d "card[cvc]"=314
```

In my component to get the values and send it to the service

```
cardForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  'card[number]': ['', Validators.required],
  'card[exp_month]': ['', Validators.required],
  'card[exp_year]': ['', Validators.required],
  'card[cvc]': ['', Validators.required],
});

cardSubmit(){
  console.log(this.cardForm.value);
  this._paymentsService.generateToken(this.cardForm.value).subscribe(
    response => {
      console.log(response);
    },
    error => {
      console.error(<any>error);
    }
  );
}
```

And in the service to send to Stripe I have like this

```
generateToken(card) :Observable<any>{
    let params = card;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded').set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ this.tokenPublic);
    return this._http.post(this.tokenStripe, params, {headers:headers});
}
```

> I update my code but doesnt work

```
cardSubmit(){
    let something = {
      card: {
        number: this.cardForm.value.number, 
        exp_month: this.cardForm.value.exp_month,
        exp_year: this.cardForm.value.exp_year,
        cvc: this.cardForm.value.cvc
      }
    }
    this._paymentsService.generateToken(something).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: You should only use Elements to collect card details securely and you should not be trying to emulate the curl request or touch the card details yourself for PCI compliance. Make sure to look at elements https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements

Comment: @koopajah do you have an example or docs where I can see the implement of stripe js to make subscriptions? I want to use stripe to make subscriptions to my client web app

Comment: There are many examples end to end in Stripe's documentation with everything you need such as https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price

Comment: Hey have you got the solution ?? I also want to do the same. please let me know

Comment: @ManishPatidar yes I got it, someone told me that for security i can't make it with cURL so, in my front I just generate a paynment method token with ngx-stripe then I send it to my back end (In my case with laravel) and then I make all the other things, If you want I can told you the steps is no more than 4 steps for me

Comment: @cesg.dav can you please tell me what are the steps?

Comment: @ManishPatidar For sure!... sorry for the delay
1. You need to create a customer from the back end
2. create a payment method with Stripe since the front
3. then I attach the payment method to the customer
4. last you need to create the subscription. If you want I can post my code as a response to my question

Comment: @cesg.dav yes please put your code so I'll get an idea,
Just let me know how you have managed to generate tokens with the reactive form fields.

Comment: @ManishPatidar actually I dont use the reactive forms just for assing the name phone and email but for the card data i use stripe elements https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/

Comment: @ManishPatidar I just post the answer, hope it help you

Answer (score 1):

> Create a customer since the back

use the service from the front to send the data to create the customer

```
this.userService.makeUser(this.personalInfo.value).subscribe(
  response => {
    if (response.status == 'success') {
    }
)
```

then since the back create the customer and return to the front to take some data that we will need after

```
public function register(Request $request) {
    $json = $request->input('json', null);
    $params = json_decode($json);
    $params_array = json_decode($json, true);

    
    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
        'stripe key'
    );

    $stripe = $stripe->customers->create([
        'email' => $params->email,
        'name' => $params->name.' '.$params->surname,
        'description' => 'Suscripcion a Maranda CTI',
    ]);
}
```

in the front we will create the payment method than after we will attach to the client

```
this.stripeService
.createPaymentMethod({
  type: 'card',
  card: this.card.element,
  billing_details: { name },
})
.subscribe((result) => {
  if (result.paymentMethod) {
  }
)
```

after we have the payment method created we send to the back to attach to the customer... at this point remember that have the data when create the customer from the back so we need to send to the back that customer id and the payment method id

```
this.userService.attachPaymentMethod(this.someform.value).subscribe(
  response => {
  }
)
```

and in the back we create the attachment and the subscription

```
public function attach(Request $request){
    $json = $request->input('json', null);
    $params = json_decode($json);

    if($params->gratis == 'No'){

        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
            'stripe key'
        );

        $stripeAttach = $stripe->paymentMethods->attach(
            $params->pm,
            ['customer' => $params->idcus]
        );

        $intent = $stripe->paymentIntents->create([
            'amount' => $params->amount,
            'currency' => 'mxn',
            'payment_method_types'=>['card'],
            'payment_method' => $params->pm,
            'customer' => $params->idcus,
            'description' => 'Associate cc with cust for subscription'
        ]);

        $stripeConfirm = $stripe->paymentIntents->confirm(
            $intent->id
        );

        if($stripeConfirm->status == 'succeeded'){

            $stripe_sub = $stripe->subscriptions->create([
                'customer' =>  $params->idcus,
                'default_payment_method' => $params->pm,
                'items' => [
                    ['price' => $params->planId],
                ],
            ]);
        }

        if($stripe_sub){

            $data = array(
                'usuario' => $stripe_sub,
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => 'El usuario se ha registrado correctamente. Se ha enviado un correo electrónico con su información de inicio de sesión.',
                'code' => 200
            );

        } else {

            $data = array(
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Ha ocurrido un error, intentelo de nuevo.',
                'code' => 400
            );

        }
    }
}
```

And that's how you have a subscription